# Социальные сети аналогов которых нету в СНГ

Tags: проект

Может кто знает социалки аналогов которых пока нету в СНГ?

Comment: Хочеться сорвать куш? :D Придумывайте свое

Comment: Нет, просто интересно. К примеру Pinterest.com и точна такая же Pinme.ru. Или же seamessage.ru и seamessage.com. А есть ли без аналогов?))

Comment: у гугл+ нет аналогов))

Comment: @namak так-то у него и отличительных уж особенностей нет

Comment: ну вот вам и цель: сможете без желания навязать нескольким миллионам пользователям соц сеть?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [list social network](https://www.google.com/search?rls=ru&q=list+social+network)
2. [Результат](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_social_networking_websites)

Уделить время, посмотреть и найти возможные схожести!

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки!

Answer (score 1):

Только те, о которых мы не знаем по причине их непопулярности/низкой популярности (что не одно и то же).

Если github считать социалкой (он же заявляет о себе как о месте, где можно творить "Social Coding") - то нет, не видел. Да и смысла в таком аналоге не думаю, что много. Хотя, кто знает?..

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Будем думать дальше...